# SupportMapFragment returns null

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-api-3

I have read the already related questions and I could not find an answer to my problem.

**The app structure**

Our `MainActivity` is a `FragmentTabHost` so it holds fragments. One of the fragments that I would like to show has another fragment inside - the `SupportMapFragment`.

We have a second activity which is `LoginActivity`.

**The problem**

When going through the fragments, there is no issue in going back to my `MyMapFragment`. However, when I open the `LoginActivity` and just close it I get a null pointer exception. The NPE is on this line

```
googleMap = fragment.getMap();
```

and what actually is null is the `fragment`.

What I do not understand is, how can it find it the "first" time it loads, but cannot find it the second time?

I know that `getMap()` is depricated, however that is not the case. I cannot get `fragment` object.

I have tried with the `getMapAsync()`, but it wouldn't work either. The first time I would get a call to the `onMapReady()`, but if you switch forth and back to the `LoginActivity` the `onMapReady()` callback is never returned.

**My question is:** How do I "reset" the `SupportMapFragment` in order to obtain it when I call the `findFragmentById`?

This is an overview of `MyMapFragment`

```
public class MyMapFragment extends Fragment
{
    GoogleMap googleMap;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        if (_view != null)
        {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) _view.getParent();

            if (parent != null)
            {
                parent.removeView(_view);
            }
        }       
        else
        {
            try
            {
                _view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mymapfragment, container, false);
            }
            catch (InflateException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);

        googleMap = fragment.getMap(); // fragment is null after going to another activity
    }
}
```

The `map_fragment.xml`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- some other stuff -->
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: `getMap()` returns null that because that method is deprecated. Try to use `getMapAsync (OnMapReadyCallback callback)` instead.

Comment: @bjiang If you read what I have written carefully I have addressed both your sentences. It is not `getMap()` which is null, the `fragment` is null. I tried using a `getMapAsync()`, but the callback would not be received the second time I switch to the fragment.

Comment: A view can be removed when the `SupportMapFragment's onDestroyView()` method is called and the `useViewLifecycleInFragment(boolean)` option is set. When this happens the SupportMapFragment is no longer valid until the view is recreated again later when SupportMapFragment's `onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)` method is called.